# iAds not showing in released iPhone app

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, iad

I just my app got approved and when I downloaded the app ,iAds are not showing up, when I saw the status of iAds it says"**You have enabled at least one application for iAd, but you will not be able to view the iAd Network module or set your ad preferences until you have an iAd Network Contract in effect.**", Although I have setup all my contacts informations for setting iAds and it also show effective date.If anyone get the same thing please let me know the solution.

Comment: You might be missing some configurations into your itunesconnect app details for iAd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by mailing and contacting apple. Its look like they have forget to enable the iAds, when I contacted them, my iADs are started running live next day.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing a contract agreement. Login to itunesconnect.apple.com, go to the Contracts, Tax and Banking section and fill in the contact info and bank info for iAd network.

If you have them in place, it might be that Apple is verifying the info. As soon as it is verified, your ads should start working.